# Dissoc multiple descendent keys of a map?

Tags: clojure

How can I search and dissoc multiple descendent keys.

Example:

```
(def d {:foo 123
        :bar {
          :baz 456
          :bam {
            :whiz 789}}})

(dissoc-descendents d [:foo :bam])
;->> {:bar {:baz 456}}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[clojure.walk](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.walk) is useful in this kind of situations:

```
(use 'clojure.walk)
(postwalk #(if (map? %) (dissoc % :foo :bam) %) d)
```

Comment: Postwalk does depth-first traversal. I guess for this situation a breadth-first traversal search will be much better in efficiency because if a parent node is to be removed then we wont need to traverse its children

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to implement it directly then I'd suggest something like this:

```
(defn dissoc-descendents [coll descendents]
  (let [descendents (if (set? descendents) descendents (set descendents))]
    (if (associative? coll)
      (reduce
        (fn [m [k v]] (if (descendents k) 
                        (dissoc m k)
                        (let [new-val (dissoc-descendents v descendents)]
                          (if (identical? new-val v) m (assoc m k new-val)))))
        coll
        coll)
      coll)))
```

Key things to note about the implementation:

- It makes sense to convert descendents into a set: this will allow quick membership tests if the set of keys to remove is large
- There is some logic to ensure that if a value doesn't change, you don't need to alter that part of the map. This is quite a big performance win if large areas of the map are unchanged.